# Расположение элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как сделать расположение элементов в RecyclerView примерно как на картинке? Каким layoutManager при этом пользоваться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/39484534/3069565

Comment: И эту [библиотеку](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5875).

Comment: eugeneek, спасибо, ответ помог